# Chrome background image gets cut

Tags: javascript, css

When you scroll to the last div and go up the background image is cutted at the top. This happens only in chrome and is not happening in Firefox etc. I've searched stack overflow and other sites for a solution, since its a known and old bug. The solutions that I could find were not really applicable to my design that I want to stay intact.

The bug gets triggerd because of the diagonal css3 I used at the scrollable div and the canvas. When I use either in the scrollable div I get this problem.

URL of the page http://goo.gl/tbQ5Rm

If someone has had this same problem and fixed it.. Please let me know :)

Here you can see a snapshot of the issue

[image: Screenshot_1_issue_image_cropped]

<sub>Click to enlarge the image</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by "cutted"? the background image is cropped? or its not visible ? Can u add the screenshot of your bug so it's easy to understand want you're trying to say.?

Comment: The image gets cropped visually but it is in fact not really cropped. If you hide/show the background image in the css it is shown fully. Also when you select the text and go up, you will see more of the image.

 There is a screenshot added, couldn't upload it via stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the z-index in the third `<div>` element,

```
<div id="section3" class="section pp-section" style="top: 0px;">
```

and have the z-index as 4 for the first second `<div>` element

```
<div id="section1" class="section pp-section" style="top: -100%; z-index: 4;">
```

and keep the z-index as 2 for the second `<div>` element

```
<div id="section2" class="section pp-section" style="top: -100%; z-index: 2;">
```

The above code works fine for me with the changes I made in firebug.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Im going to implement it asap and get back to you.